# Making the SIM800L GSM module to send its own phone number when making a voice call

Tags: sim800l, caller-id

I connected the GSM module to an Arduino Mini Pro and control it with AT commands. I can make a phone call, but the calle phone does not display the callers number. It displays "No caller ID". Although if i put the same SIM card into an old mobile phone and call the same phone than it displays the correct number.

This is what I sent:

AT               // wait for OK

AT+CREG=1        // wait for CREG=1

ATD+XXxxxxxxxxx; // wait for OK.

the call is always succesful.

Is there any way to force the GSM module to send its phone number?

Thanks!

Comment: I called the mobile service provider, and it turned out that they can enable it. So if it is not overridden by the mobile phone, the default is not to send the number. My old phone overrides this, but the GSM module not. So I had to have the service provider make it to be the default.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from here:
https://forum.arduino.cc/t/sim800l-call-private-number/543322

```
AT+CLIR=
```

**Response**

TA restricts or enables the presentation of the CLI to the called party when originating a call.

The Command overrides the CLIR subscription (default is restricted or allowed) when temporary mode is provisioned as a default adjustment for all following outgoing calls. This adjustment can be revoked by using the opposite Command.

OK

If error is related to ME functionality:
+CME ERROR:

**Parameters**

(parameter sets the adjustment for outgoing calls):

0 Presentation indicator is used according to the subscription of the CLIR service.

1 CLIR invocation

2 CLIR suppression

(parameter shows the subscriber CLIR service status in the network):

0 CLIR not provisioned

1 CLIR provisioned in permanent mode

2 Unknown (e.g. no network, etc.)

3 CLIR temporary mode presentation restricted

4 CLIR temporary mode presentation allowed